# Mina deployment - Make sure that `gem install mime-types-data -v '3.2016.0221'` succeeds before bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, digital-ocean

I followed this tutorial to deploy my app with mina gem- [tutorial](http://blog.mccartie.com/2014/08/28/digital-ocean.html)

here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/krishnateja/a1501fc371e5d375c80f0e83ae5ec88b) and logs

```
Krishna Teja (fbc9a1f):
> modified series_controller callback definition

-----> Symlinking shared paths
-----> Installing gem dependencies using Bundler
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (11.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.7.0) 
Using json (1.8.3) 
Using minitest (5.8.4) 
Using thread_safe (0.3.5) 
Using tzinfo (1.2.2) 
Using activesupport (4.2.5.1) 
Using builder (3.2.2) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using mini_portile2 (2.0.0) 
Using nokogiri (1.6.7.2) 
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3) 
Using rails-dom-testing (1.0.7) 
Using loofah (2.0.3) 
Using rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3) 
Using actionview (4.2.5.1) 
Using rack (1.6.4) 
Using rack-test (0.6.3) 
Using actionpack (4.2.5.1) 
Using globalid (0.3.6) 
Using activejob (4.2.5.1) 
Installing mime-types-data (3.2016.0221) 
Gem::InstallError: mime-types-data requires Ruby version >= 2.0.
An error occurred while installing mime-types-data (3.2016.0221), and      Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mime-types-data -v '3.2016.0221'` succeeds before bundling.
! ERROR: Deploy failed.
-----> Cleaning up build
Unlinking current
OK
Connection to 139.59.6.50 closed.

 !     Command failed.
       Failed with status 1 (4864)
```

I would really appreciate if someone can throw some light on what am missing.

Comment: It says it right in the error logs. To use the `mime-types-data` gem, you need to be using Ruby v2+. What version of ruby are you using? `ruby --version` to find out.

Comment: This is the version `ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]`. However sudo `ruby --version` gives this `ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]`. Also when I do `gem install mime-types-data -v 3.2016.0221` in the terminal, gem is getting installed properly.

Comment: Are you positive that is the version of ruby being used when deploying with mina? Your script is loading the `rbenv` component. Is `rbenv` actually installed on that machine and located where it expects it (`$HOME/.rbenv`)?

Comment: Yeah that's the version of Ruby, rbenv is installed and 2+ version is set globally. Have been pulling my hair since 6 hours but no luck.  Have come across a article which says that's a bug but unable to find a workaround for it.

Comment: Did you try uncommenting the following 2 lines (line number 25 in your gist)?
# For system-wide RVM install.
#   set :rvm_path, '/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm'